# Shell script to check if running in Windows when using WSL?

Tags: windows, shell, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to add a conditional to my .zshrc file that will initialize some config stuff that I only want to happen if I'm in Windows Subsystem for Linux. I tried this but no luck:

```
if [ "$('cmd.exe /c "systeminfo" | grep "^OS Name"')" =~ "Windows" ]; then
        echo "windows baby!"
fi
```

Which gives:

```
no such file or directory: cmd.exe /c "systeminfo" | grep "^OS Name"
```

...but that command works if I type it directly in the shell.
Any ideas?

Comment: I have never used WSL, so just a wild guess: What does `uname` say when you are in WSL?

Comment: Look at the head of /etc/profile there is a check. Just do it in the same way

Comment: @user1934428 "Linux" :/

Comment: @MatthewMasurka : And `uname -a` also does not show something significant? Of course the idea by Carlos Rafael Ramirez looks more promising anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `uname -r` does the trick

According to https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/423#issuecomment-608236476, if you use

```
uname -r | sed -n 's/.*\( *Microsoft *\).*/\1/ip'
```

You'll get output as "Microsoft" in case it is WSL. Otherwise, you should get no output.

So you can use something like

```
if [ $(uname -r | sed -n 's/.*\( *Microsoft *\).*/\1/ip') ];
then
        echo "This is Windows WSL baby!"
else
        echo "Not Windows"
fi
```